# Build Streaming Data Architecture on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-lambda, streaming

I would like to design a streaming data architecture for my company's project.

Basically, we receive the records which are user's information and we need to use this information to calculate some metrices in real time, and then send these metrices to marketing department for further analysis.

Currently, we have a backend team that receives these records, transforms them to useful data and store them in a S3 bucket. We also have a lambda function that is triggered by this S3 bucket; inside this lambda function we calculate these metrics and store them in RDS.

Normally, we receive about 6k-7k records per day and this architecture still works fine. The problem of this architecture is that it is not easy to scale up due to the restriction on time and memory of lambda functions. There were some days that we receive a lot of record in a short time. Therefore, lambda function is unable to handle these record within 15 minutes (this is the restriction of lambda function).

I have been looking at other architectures to solve this problem. One alternative is that I will use Spark instead of Lambda function, because there is no restriction on Spark and it is easy to scale. But I am wondering if Spark will work and the pricing cost of it. If not, can you provide other architectures for me?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to approach this, and they will depend on the specifics of what you're doing. Some of the things to research are Kinesis, Kinesis Analytics, Athena, Refshift, and Redshift Spectrum. If your Lambdas are timing out, I would look at AWS Batch before jumping to Glue, especially given the number of records that you're processing.

Comment: But before doing any of that, I would take a close look at your current implementation, and figure out why a Lambda is timing out for 7,000 records. My guess is that you're interacting with some other system, and that's what's causing the timeout. It will also be what prevents you from scaling, regardless of the technology you decide to use.

Comment: @Parsifal Normally, my lambda works fine when we have average 7000 records per day, but there were some days we have a lot more than 7000 records (~100k), then my lambda reaches the limit. In addition, the metric calculation I mentioned involves selecting and updating data from historical database, since the data is huge, these queries take a lot time (in some cases, it takes ~60s to execute a single query update). Do you think I should use Spark or other systems to replace Lambda ?

Comment: I can't give you a recommendation based on what you've written. But before I switched platforms I would (1) investigate ways to break the workload into manageable chunks, and (2) think of ways to reduce the overall processing time, especially the queries against the historical database.